# z-index в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, z-index

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

var previous,
  inputSize = document.querySelector("[name='size']"),
  rect;

function Paint(elem) {
  var x,
    y,
    width,
    height;

  this.image = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    color: 'black',
    tool: null,

    coordsOfCanvas: () => {
      return canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    },
  };

  this.mouseDown = false;

  this.pencil = () => {
    this.image.tool = 'pencil';
    ctx.lineWidth = inputSize.value = '5';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';

    inputSize.parentNode.style.display = 'table-cell';
  };

  this.brush = () => {
    this.image.tool = 'brush';
    ctx.lineWidth = inputSize.value = '25';
    ctx.lineCap = 'butt';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';

    inputSize.parentNode.style.display = 'table-cell';
  };

  this.fill = () => {
    this.image.tool = 'fill';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black'

    inputSize.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  };

  this.clear = () => {
    this.image.tool = 'clear';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.lineWidth = inputSize.value = '20';
    ctx.lineCap = 'butt';

    inputSize.parentNode.style.display = 'table-cell';
  };

  this.rectangle = () => {
    this.image.tool = 'rectangle';
    inputSize.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  };

  //Координаты мыши относительно canvas
  this.getCoords = () => {
    this.image.x = event.clientX - this.image.coordsOfCanvas().left;
    this.image.y = event.clientY - this.image.coordsOfCanvas().top;
  }

  elem.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    this.mouseDown = true;
    this.getCoords();

    if (this.image.tool == 'fill') {
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    } else if ((this.image.tool == 'pencil' ||
        this.image.tool == 'brush' ||
        this.image.tool == 'clear') && this.mouseDown) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.image.x, this.image.y);
    } else if (this.image.tool == 'rectangle' && this.mouseDown) {
      //Фиксируем начальные координаты
      x = this.image.x;
      y = this.image.y;
    }

    elem.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
      this.getCoords();

      if ((this.image.tool == 'pencil' ||
          this.image.tool == 'brush' ||
          this.image.tool == 'clear') && this.mouseDown) {
        ctx.lineWidth = inputSize.value;
        ctx.lineTo(this.image.x, this.image.y);
        ctx.stroke();
      }

      if (this.image.tool == 'rectangle' && this.mouseDown) {
        ctx.clearRect(x, y, width - x, height - y)
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, this.image.x - x, this.image.y - y)
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'

        //Сохраняем предыдущие координаты мыши
        width = this.image.x;
        height = this.image.y;
      }
    });

  });

  elem.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    this.mouseDown = false;

    if (this.image.tool == 'rectangle') {
      x = y = height = width = null;
    }
  });


  document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let target = event.target;
    let action = target.getAttribute('data-type');

    if (action) {

      if (previous) {
        previous.classList.remove('active');
      }

      target.classList.add('active');
      previous = target;
      this[action]();
    };

  });
};

new Paint(canvas);
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0;
}

.draw {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.options {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #575a5e;
  z-index: 1;
}

.options label {
  display: block;
}

.options ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.options ul li {
  display: none;
  height: 48px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tools {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 48px;
  background: #575a5e;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tools>div {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

.tools div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pencil {
  background: url('icons.png');
  background-position-x: 0;
}

.brush {
  background: url('icons.png');
  background-position-x: -48px;
}

.clear {
  background: url('icons.png');
  background-position-x: -96px;
}

.fill {
  background: url('icons.png');
  background-position-x: -144px;
}

.rectangle {
  background: url('icons.png');
  background-position-x: -48px;
  background-position-y: -48px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #cdd0d6;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='tools'>
  <div class='pencil' data-type='pencil'></div>
  <div class='brush' data-type='brush'></div>
  <div class='fill' data-type='fill'></div>
  <div class='clear' data-type='clear'></div>
  <div class='rectangle' data-type='rectangle' style='background: green'></div>
</div>
<div class='options'>
  <ul>
    <li class='size'>
      <label for="size">Size(1-50): </label>
      <input type="number" id="size" name='size' min="1" max="50" value=''>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class='draw'>
  <canvas width='800px' height='500px' id='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

У меня 2 вопроса:

1) Возможно ли как-нибудь образом реализовать наложение рисованных фигур одну на вторую? На данный момент, если наложить 1 прямоугольник на 2, не отпуская лкм, а затем 1-ому уменьшить размер - сотрёт часть уже нарисованного.

2) Если нарисовать несколько прямоугольников, некоторые их части пропадают с canvas чудесным образом :) Из-за чего?

P.S. Выбрать рисование прямоугольником - нажать на зелёный div

Comment: так не получится, необходимо хранить массив фигур и на каждое изменение стирать всю канву и рисовать все фигуры по новой. иначе информация о уже закрашенных пикселях будет утеряна, после рисования поверх них.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, спасибо за совет, мне этого уже достаточно :) А по поводу 2 пункта, есть какие-нибудь соображения?

Comment: а это какой-то баг в коде, я думаю его не станет, если Вы напишете новую реализацию (надо дебажить)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примерно то, о чем я писал в комментарии

```js
let a, c = canvas.getContext('2d'), s = canvas.width, r = [];

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => 
    r.push(a = [e.x,e.y,0,0,`hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,55%)`]));

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => a = null);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (!a) return;
  a[2] = e.x - a[0], a[3] = e.y - a[1];
  c.clearRect(0, 0, s, s);
  let t = new Date;
  r.forEach(r => (c.fillStyle = r[4]) && c.fillRect(...r));
  c.fillText(r.length + ' - ' + (new Date - t) + 'ms', 3, 10);
})
```

```css
body{margin:0}canvas{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.05)}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="635" height="175"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться :)

Comment: ща проверил, на i7 8700., 10000 фигур ~ 35мс