# Как отрисовать объекты в массиве на Javascript?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Пишу что-то вроде старого платформера lode runner. У меня генерируется массив, получая количество строк и ячеек из переменных в классе config. Также создается таблица в html файле. Мне нужно заполнить некоторые элементы массива значениями, соответствующими определенным объектам.

```
    class Level {

    constructor() {
        this.map = [];
    }

    init(settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    createLevelMap() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.settings.rowsCount; i++) {
            let newRow = [];
            this.map.push(newRow);
            for (let j = 0; j < this.settings.colsCount; j++) {
                let newCol = '';
                this.map[i].push(newCol);
            }
        }
    }

    renderLevelMap() {
        let table = document.createElement('table');
        for (let i = 0; i < this.settings.rowsCount; i++) {
            let tRow = document.createElement('tr');
            table.appendChild(tRow);
            for (let j = 0; j < this.settings.colsCount; j++) {
                let tCol = document.createElement('td');
                tRow.appendChild(tCol);
            }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(table);
    }

}
```

Придумал я значит делать так:

let ground = [[10,11,1,4][...][...]] тут каждый массив это платформа, которую нужно отрисовать, первый элемент в массиве это координата y, вторая x, потом толщина, потом сколько ячеек в строке (ширина) платформы.

Ну и допустим let groundSymbol = '#' это символ, который нужно будет вставить в элемент массива

Итог: должно получиться что в массиве игрового поля по индексу 10 берем 11 элемент и поскольку ширина у нас 4, то по 14 элемент включительно записываем значение '#' и так с каждым последующим массивом, которые лежат в ground

Подскажите как такое реализовать вообще? Я ничего другого не придумал

Comment: не понятно, начиная с groundSymbol

Comment: извиняюсь, коряво описал

Comment: если я верно понял -  я писал сегодня похожий ответ про канву https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/996104/188366

Comment: у нас есть массив из 10 массивов, в каждом из которых 10 элементов (игровое поле 10х10), есть переменная ground, в которой у нас массив, в котором тоже лежат массивы (каждый из которых представляет сущность платформы), например [10,10, 1, 4], тут первый элемент массива это индекс строки, второй индекс ячейки для игрового поля, 1 это толщина (количество строк), а 4 это ширина, т.е. сколько элементов он по горизонтали занимает, т.е. перенося это на игровое поле нужно заполнить 4 элемента по горизонтали символом '#' начиная со строки 10 и элемента 10

Comment: отлично, а проблема в чем?

Comment: Я не могу придумать как это реализовать (

Comment: реализовать заполнение поля в соответствии с массивом объектов?

Comment: Да. Именно так.

Comment: самый простой вариант - алгоритм художника. это когда вы не экономите процессорное время, а рисуете объекты, которые закрывают друг друга в определенном порядке и если вткакой то ячейке уже есть информация о каком то объекте - вы ее затираете новой... в итоге получается не оптимально (overdraw), зато код проще.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0